# Message from event viewer, what does it mean?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, event-viewer

.NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.34209 - The profiler was loaded successfully.  Profiler CLSID: '{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}'.  Process ID (decimal): 1440.  Message ID: [0x2507].